# How many devil fruits we know about have been discovered?

Tags: one-piece

I was wondering how many devil fruits have we seen in the manga since the beginning ?

Has someone ever counted how many of them exist ?

Comment: -1 for no research effort, they're listed on the first page you get when you google them: [Zoan](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Zoan), [Logia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Logia), [Paramecia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Paramecia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of devil fruits from the start of the manga till today is as follows [ taken from the one piece wikia ]   :

```
             Canon   Non-canon    SBS[I'm Taking Questions by Oda]

Paramecia       74          25      2

Zoan            29*          6      0

Logia           12           3      0

Unspecified      1           1      1

Total          116          35      3
```

*The number excludes artificial devil fruits .